# NRST pin goes low when externally powered the STM32L432KC with 5V at 5V pin

Tags: stm32, reset, microchip, stm32cubeide, dac

When I tried to power STM32L432KC board  externally with 5V supplying the voltage at pin 5V directly, it causes NRST pin to go low and the board becomes unresponsive, means there is no DAC Output connected to multimeter. Shall I pull up NRST pin externally? Please let me know your suggestions.

Is there any way to solve this issue or I miss any efficient way to power STM32L432KC externally with 5V? My goal is to run this board with external 5V power supply and want some DAC output.

Comment: It's very unclear what your problem is. NRST is an _input_ to the STM32, so yes, you should be controlling it. A pull-up seems sensible. I don't know what you mean by "goes low".Anyway, this doesn't seem to be about software. If you're still stuck, ask your question on [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)